# Just assigning variables, contains a reference with a non-static lifetime so can't be persisted

Tags: rust

I'm working through the big crab book learning Rust:

[image]

But when I execute this code, I see the following errors:

```rust
let hello = &s[0..5];
let hello = &s[0..5];
    ^^^^^ 
The variable `hello` contains a reference with a non-static lifetime so can't be persisted

let world = &s[6..11];
let world = &s[6..11];
    ^^^^^ 
The variable `world` contains a reference with a non-static lifetime so can't be persisted
```

What does this mean?  This is early on in the introduction to slices.

Comment: ummm, are you using evcxr? https://github.com/google/evcxr/issues/137

Comment: try running this code inside `fn main(){/* ... */}` ? In the outter scope,  `'static` is required, in general.

Comment: I guess that's it.  It had to be inside a main